# a proper way to escape %% when building LIKE queries in Rails 3 / ActiveRecord

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I want to match a url field against a url prefix (which may contain percent signs), e.g. `.where("url LIKE ?", "#{some_url}%")`.
What's the most Rails way?

Comment: I hope you don't have any plans to scale to millions of posts.  That query will suck system resources faster than an SUV drains gas out of a tank.

Comment: @Wes: Depends on your database. AFAIK, recent versions of PostgreSQL can utilize an index for LIKE matches that use a prefix (i.e. those of the form `X%` for some fixed `X`). There are some notes on this over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations

Comment: @Wes: You're still hosed with `%X%` patterns though, that'll almost certainly hand you a table scan. Sorry that I don't have an authoritative reference but you could probably grok a query plan and see what happens.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're worried about "%" appearing inside `some_url` and rightly so; you should also be worried about embedded underscores ("_") too, they're the LIKE version of "." in a regex. I don't think there is any Rails-specific way of doing this so you're left with `gsub`:

```
.where('url like ?', some_url.gsub('%', '\\\\\%').gsub('_', '\\\\\_') + '%')
```

There's no need for string interpolation here either. You need to double the backslashes to escape their meaning from the database's string parser so that the LIKE parser will see simple "\%" and know to ignore the escaped percent sign.

You should check your logs to make sure the two backslashes get through. I'm getting confusing results from checking things in `irb`, using five (!) gets the right output but I don't see the sense in it; if anyone does see the sense in five of them, an explanatory comment would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**: Jason King has kindly offered a simplification for the nightmare of escaped escape characters. This lets you specify a [temporary escape character](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/functions-matching.html) so you can do things like this:

```
.where("url LIKE ? ESCAPE '!'", some_url.gsub(/[!%_]/) { |x| '!' + x })
```

I've also switched to the block form of `gsub` to make it a bit less nasty.

This is standard SQL92 syntax, so will work in any DB that supports that, including PostgreSQL, MySQL and SQLite.

Embedding one language inside another is always a bit of a nightmarish kludge and there's not that much you can do about it. There will always be ugly little bits that you just have to grin and bear.

Comment: Btw, if (I don't know) you need to get double-backslashes into those strings, the above won't do it.  `'\\' => \` in Ruby (and most languages).

Comment: @Jason: Five escapes produces the right thing in `irb`, thanks for catching that. I'm guessing that it goes through as three tokens "\\", "\\", and "\%" which, after escape processing, ends up as "\\%" as desired. I usually just keep adding them until it works then reverse engineer the justification. Does anyone know of a quote operator that really does produce literal results without any processing or big pile of mess?

Comment: Something else you could do is to add an `ESCAPE` clause, like this: `.where( "url LIKE ? ESCAPE '!'", some_url.gsub('%', '!%').gsub('_', '!_')`

Comment: @Jason: That's genius. I wish I could give you points for a comment or just transfer ownership of the answer to you.

Comment: @mu Unfortunately, your answer is probably correct. The only (barely convincing) reason for such a nuisance I can think of: LIKE queries suck, and should not generally be used.

Comment: @Costa: Thanks for the correction. Sometimes you have a choice between different types of pain: use LIKE or SIMILAR TO inside the database and deal with the quoting nonsense or pull a ton of stuff out of the database, do the pattern matching in Ruby, and then throw most of the data away. Six of one, half a dozen of the other.

Comment: @mu - you're welcome - and no worries about the points, these things have a way of working themselves out in the end.

Comment: You could also use capturing groups instead of the block syntax (shorter and probably faster): `.where("url LIKE ? ESCAPE '!'", some_url.gsub(/([!%_])/, '!\1')`

Comment: @RecursivelyIronic: I rarely use that form of `gsub`, the double meaning of backslashes can be problematic so I usually just go with the block form when working with a non-constant replacement so that I don't have to worry about when backslashes need to be doubled and when they don't. But that's just personal preference.

Answer (score 27):

From Rails version 4.2.x there is an active record method called `sanitize_sql_like`. So, you can do in your model a search scope like:

```
scope :search, -> search { where('"accounts"."name" LIKE ?', "#{sanitize_sql_like(search)}%") }
```

and call the scope like:

```
Account.search('Test_%')
```

The resulting escaped sql string is:

```
SELECT "accounts".* FROM "accounts" WHERE ("accounts"."name" LIKE 'Test\_\%%')
```

Read more here: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods.html

Comment: In my opinion, this is the most elegant way to solve this issue

Comment: Guess from rails 5.* sanitize_sql_like is not supported
Any other alternative?

Comment: It is supported on Rails 5.x. See here https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.2.1.1/activerecord/lib/active_record/sanitization.rb#L107

Comment: FYI these are protected/private methods on 5.0 and 5.1. They're only public on 5.2.

Comment: @Teoulas is right. Rails 5.0 and 5.1, use this to call them: `ActiveRecord::Base.send(:sanitize_sql_like, "Test_%")`

Answer (score 6):

https://gist.github.com/3656283

With this code,

`Item.where(Item.arel_table[:name].matches("%sample!%code%"))`

correctly escapes `%` between "sample" and "code", and matches "AAAsample%codeBBB" but does not for "AAAsampleBBBcodeCCC" on MySQL, PostgreSQL and SQLite3 at least.

Answer (score -3):

```
Post.where('url like ?', "%#{some_url + '%'}%)
```

Comment: @Sam Very close. `Post.where('url like ?', "%#{some_url}%")`

Comment: You code just makes a like condition match other entries. @Costa-Shaprio is looking for a way to do what your doing plus having `%` or at least that is how I'm reading it ie 'which may contain percent signs'

Comment: @Rein: No. That changes the nature of the match ("begins with" becomes "anywhere in") and does nothing to account for an embedded "%" in `some_url` let alone underscores.

Comment: @mu Ok, remove the first % then. That's a simple requirements misunderstanding. It still works for the 90% case. And at least it's syntactically valid, which `"%#{some_url + '%'}%` is not.

Comment: @mu Did you check to see if ActiveRecord's sql sanitization already escapes %s before you commented?

Comment: @Rein: How would AR tell the difference between an intentional `%x%x%` and an accidental `"%#{a}%"` when `a` just happens to be an unescaped `'x%x'`? The first (intentional) case wants "*anything* x *anything* x *anything*" whereas the second would want "*anything* x%x *anything*" but get "*anything* x *anything* x *anything*" because no one escaped it. By the time AR sees the argument for LIKE, it just has a string that has embedded SQL syntax and it is too late to infer the programmer's intent.

Comment: @ReinH - it doesn't, %s are not escaped by AR - nor is there a % escaper anywhere in AR.

Comment: Yes, I understand what % means and why it is important to escape it. I was just trying to fix a syntax error. Please direct your corrections to the original answer.

Comment: bottom line the answer is not good. it wont escape %s in the url. I can't believe rails have no native answer for that. wtf?

Comment: yeah, it's not good. can you give examples of your urls that you need to get searched? That's why my answer sucks, I just pasted some code that was kinda related to you answer. Post some examples of the urls you wan to search.