# How can I convert a Postgres database to sqlite DB with a unix friendly tool?

Tags: database, sqlite, postgresql, database-migration

I have a postgres database on the server and we are building a iPhone app and need the database in Sqlite format.

Someone has already asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148421/how-to-convert-a-postgres-database-to-sqlite) but the linked tools are mostly windows based GUI tools. Is there a linux friendly tool to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pg_dump --column-inserts` should give you a good starting point for a script to recreate the database in SQLite. It should then be possible to write something to transform this SQL and convert types and concepts, e.g. presumably sequences for primary keys will have to be converted to auto-inc qualifications?