# How to convert Postgres dump file to Sqlite file

Tags: postgresql, sqlite

I'm trying to use the `pg_dump` command to generate a file from the whole database which includes some tables from Postgresql:

```
pg_dump -h <my postgres host> -U <my user name> -Fc <my database name> > pg.dump
```

I want to convert this `pg.dump` file to `pg.sqlite`, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Do not use the custom format, use insert statements. After that some manual work may be needed, but it's a lot simpler.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert a postgres database to sqlite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148421/how-to-convert-a-postgres-database-to-sqlite)