# export table as a new table in new sqlite3 db

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a way to export an existing table from postgresql database to a new table in a new sqlite3 database ?

I have a table named `table1` in a postgres db named `db1` - need to export the table to a new sqlite3 db named `db2` and table named `table2`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a postgres database to sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148421/how-to-convert-a-postgres-database-to-sqlite)

Comment: that question is around converting a postgres DB to sqlite DB - the question here about exporting a single table from a postgres DB

Comment: That's pretty much the same. Add the `-t table1` in `pg_dump` command to export only that table.

Comment: could you please add a reference for this ?

Comment: Execute the command `pg_dump --create --inserts -f export.sql -d db1 -t table1 -U myUserName -W myPassword` to export. Find and replace from `table1` to `table2` in the SQL file.