# Convert postgres (.pgsql) data file to sqlite3 (db.sqlite3) on Ubuntu

Tags: django, postgresql, sqlite

I need to convert a postgres file into sqlite3 database file. I already have data in popstgres db. This is related to Django-webapp. Is it possible and if yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make dump of current postgresql db.
Either use pgAdmin (right click and backup) or pg_dump.

`pg_dump --data-only --inserts YOUR_DB_NAME > dump.sql'`

There could be possible also some modification, check
[convert pqsql to sqlite3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148421/how-to-convert-a-postgres-database-to-sqlite)

> Remove the lines starting with SET
>
> Remove the lines starting with SELECT pg_catalog.setval
>
> Replace true for ‘t’
>
> Replace false for ‘f’

in sqlite3

```
sqlite3 database_name
sqlite> .read 'path_to_dump.sql'
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. I am half way! created the dump.sql from pgadmin (selected data only and blobs-yes). WHile reading in sqlite3, it is showing syntax error:
Error: near line 16: near "COPY": syntax error
Error: near line 17: unrecognized token: "\"

I seelines in the dump.sql as: COPY public ....... FROM stdin;
\.

Any ideas? Thanks though for a headstart!!

Answer (score 0):

This is where I found my answer, as my problem was related to databases and django --> [here](https://www.shubhamdipt.com/blog/django-transfer-data-from-sqlite-to-another-database/).