# OperationalError at /admin/translation_manager/translationentry/ no such column: TRUE

Tags: django, django-modeltranslation

I am using django-modeltranslation for multi languages option in my django application. I followed the instruction given in documentation.
But frm admin whe I take "Translation entries" I gett an error saying

OperationalError at /admin/translation_manager/translationentry/ no such column: TRUE

Can anyone help what is this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQlite, there is a bug in `django-translation-manager/translation_manager/views.py` in query: `...WHERE te2.is_published=TRUE...`. The reason [Boolean values are stored as integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768364/activerecordstatementinvalid-sqlite3sqlexception-no-such-column-true)

To fix, change in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/translation_manager/views.py`

`...WHERE te2.is_published=TRUE...` to `...WHERE te2.is_published=1...`