# Safe ActiveRecord like query

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to write LIKE query.

I read that pure string quires aren't safe, however I couldn't find any documentation that explain how to write safe LIKE Hash Query.

Is it possible? Should I manually defend against SQL Injection?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do a LIKE query in Arel and Rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430578/how-to-do-a-like-query-in-arel-and-rails)

Answer (score 206, accepted):

To ensure that your query string gets properly sanitized, use the array or the hash query syntax to describe your conditions:

```
Foo.where("bar LIKE ?", "%#{query}%")
```

or:

```
Foo.where("bar LIKE :query", query: "%#{query}%")
```

If it is possible that the `query` might include the `%` character and you do not want to allow it (this depends on your usecase) then you need to sanitize `query` with [`sanitize_sql_like`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-sanitize_sql_like) first:

```
Foo.where("bar LIKE ?", "%#{sanitize_sql_like(query)}%")
Foo.where("bar LIKE :query", query: "%#{sanitize_sql_like(query)}%")
```

Comment: This fails to escape `%` in the query string.  It's not arbitrary "SQL injection" but still may function unexpectedly.

Comment: @BeniCherniavsky-Paskin : That is the whole point, you do not want to escape the `%` because the `%` is part of the `LIKE` syntax. If you escaped the `%` then the result would basically be a normal `=` query.

Comment: Right, YOU want to use % wildcards in your pattern template but that pattern is parametrized with `query` variable, and in many cases you want to match literally the string in `query` variable, not allow `query` to use LIKE metacharacters.  Let's take a more realistic example that %...%: the strings have a path-like structure, and you try to match `/users/#{user.name}/tags/%`.  Now if I arrange my username to be `fr%d%`, I'll be able to observe `fred` and `frida`'s tags...

Comment: OK, what I'm after is combining this question with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709887/a-proper-way-to-escape-when-building-like-queries-in-rails-3-activerecord which suggests `sanitize_sql_like()`.

Comment: @BeniCherniavsky-Paskin Now I understand where you a coming from and you are right. I updated my answer to address that issue.

Comment:  Worth also mentioning `_` and \ characters as needing escaping.

Comment: this will return value even if the params[:query] is "" or nil

Comment: @Vishal Sure, because that is how `LIKE` in SQL works. Passing an empty string to `LIKE` surrounded with `%` means: Match everything, no matter how it starts or ends. What would you expect instead?

Comment: @spickermann I expected it should return nothing but it's not possible as this is the default behavior. we have to avoid blank string externally if we don't want this behavior

Comment: Just use a conditional like `params[:query].present? ? Foo.where(like-query) : Foo.none`. There is nothing special with the `LIKE` query in this case. Even normal `where` conditions like `where(foo: params[:query])` will return unexpected results on `nil` or `''` that might need special treatment.

Answer (score 47):

Using Arel you can perform this safe and portable query:

```
title = Model.arel_table[:title]
Model.where(title.matches("%#{query}%"))
```

Comment: This is the preferable solution, since Arel is sql-db-agnostic and has some internal input cleansing. Also is much more legible and consistent as far as code-style goes, IMHO.

Comment: How do you negate this? (i.e. NOT LIKE)
`Model.where(title.matches("%#{query}%").not)`
works, although the generated SQL is a little awkward:
`WHERE (NOT (\`models\`.\`title\` LIKE '%foo%'))`

Comment: Aah...found it.   `Model.where(title.does_not_match("%#{query}%"))`.  Generates:  `WHERE (\`models\`.\`title\` NOT LIKE '%foo%')`

Comment: Careful - this fails to sanitise `%` in untrusted input:

```>> ActiveRecord::VERSION::STRING
=> "5.2.3"

>> field = Foo.arel_table[:bar]

>> Foo.where(field.matches('%')).to_sql
=> "SELECT `foos`.* FROM `foos` WHERE `foos`.`bar` LIKE '%'"```

Comment: @NoachMagedman or `Model.where.not(title.matches("%#{query}%"))`. `does_not_match` reads better though, IMO.

Comment: The problem with Arel inside a `where` method is that it doesn't work well with `joins` and often breaks scope chains. The Arel expression is converted to an sql string when passed as argument to `where`, ignoring contexts like automatically constructed table aliases in the AR evaluation. Having it coded using sql strings often makes it easier to spot such anomalies in your code.

Answer (score 9):

For PostgreSQL it will be

```
Foo.where("bar ILIKE ?", "%#{query}%")
```

Comment: The field has to be citext type to make case insensitive search work. Otherwise it will be the same as LIKE.

Answer (score 4):

In case if anyone performing search query on nested association try this:

```
Model.joins(:association).where(
   Association.arel_table[:attr1].matches("%#{query}%")
)
```

For multiple attributes try this:

```
Model.joins(:association).where(
  AssociatedModelName.arel_table[:attr1].matches("%#{query}%")
    .or(AssociatedModelName.arel_table[:attr2].matches("%#{query}%"))
    .or(AssociatedModelName.arel_table[:attr3].matches("%#{query}%"))
)
```

Don't forget to replace `AssociatedModelName` with your model name

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
MyModel.where(["title LIKE ?", "%#{params[:query]}%"])
```

Comment: @mikkeljuhl Please look at my answer carefully.

Comment: this will return value even if params[:query] is "" or nil