# Ruby on Rails query more than one fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

In my rails app, how can I query more than one fields from my database? Currently when user search for a product based on keywords, the query only get the `name` field from db:

```
@products = @products.where("lower(name) LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search_free_text].downcase}%")
```

I need to include, `description` and `highlight` both in text format into the query. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with SQL like this:

```
@products = @products.where(
  %w( name description highlight ).map { |column_name| 
    "lower(#{column_name}) LIKE :query" 
  }.join(' OR '),
  query: "%#{params[:search_free_text].downcase}%")
```

I would say this is worth it to use a scope:

```
# in your app/models/product.rb
FULLTEXT_COLUMNS = %w( name description highlight )
scope :search, lambda { |query| 
  where(
    FULLTEXT_COLUMNS.map { |c| "lower(#{c}) LIKE :query" }.join(' OR '),
    query: "%#{query.downcase}%"
  )
}

# in your controller:
@products = @products.search(params[:search_free_text])
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to follow the `SQL` format to do that:

```
@products = @products.where("lower(name) LIKE :query OR description LIKE :query", query: "%#{params[:search_free_text].downcase}%")
```

Comment: Hi, what is `params[:description_text]` is for?

Comment: That is just a assumption from my side. You need to pass the `params` for `description` you are receiving from the view

Comment: @Deep: You should not build SQL queries by string interpolation. That is insecure and could be used for [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. Always use Rails' `where('... LIKE ...')` with [an array or a hash](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26094593/2483313).

Comment: @spickermann Oh okay I have used it at some places in my project too but in model and not in controller, so using in model will be okay where there is no user params?

Comment: When you are absolutely sure it is never used with user input, then that might be okay. But I would suggest to always use the hash and array syntax to be sure that Rails quotes the queries correctly. There is no benefit in not using this security feature.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
 in a way make a scope in model `Product`

```
 class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :search_ndh, -> (name_text, desc_text, highlight_text){where("lower(name) LIKE :name OR description LIKE :desc OR highlight LIKE :high", name: "%#{name_text.downcase}%", desc: "%#{desc_text}%", high: "%#{highlight_text}%")} 
 end
```

and now use the scope

```
@products.search_ndh(params[:search_free_text].downcase, params[:search_description_text], params[:search_highlight_text])
```

or Arel ways

```
  products = Product.arel_table
  Product.where(products[:name].matches("%#{params[:search_free_text]}%").or(products[:description].matches("%#{params[:search_description_text]}%")).or(products[:highlight].matches("%#{params[:search_highlight_text]}%")))
```

or in scope by dynamic fields

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  SEARCH_COLUMNS = [:name, :description, :highlight]
  scope :search, lambda{ |q| where(SEARCH_COLUMNS.map{|c| self.arel_table[c].matches("%#{q}%").to_sql}.join(' OR '))} 
end
```

and then

```
 Product.search(params[:search_text])
```

it will generate

```
Product.search("das")

SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE ("products"."name" LIKE '%das%' OR "products"."description" LIKE '%das%' OR "products"."highlight" LIKE '%das%')
```