# My Search returns an empty array

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to make a search bar in order to find some cocktails by their name in my index. All I got is an empty array...
I believe my SQl request is not good... I'd need help please to make it working. Regards

### Here is my code:

#### Search form:

```
  <%= simple_form_for :query,  url: cocktails_path, :method => :get do |f| %>
       <%= f.input :search %>
       <%= f.button :submit %>
   <% end %>
```

### cocktails controller:

```
 def index
    if params[:query].present?
      @cocktails = Cocktail.all
      @cocktail_search = @cocktails.where('cocktails.name LIKE ?', params[:query][:search])
      binding.pry
    else
      @cocktails = Cocktail.all
    end
  end
```

#### the index view:

```
<% if @cocktail_search %>
    <% @cocktail_search.each do |cocktail| %>
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
        <div class="card"  style="background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.3), rgba(0,0,0,0.2)),
           url('<%= cl_image_path cocktail.photo %>');">

           <h2 class="card-description"><%= link_to cocktail.name, cocktail_path(cocktail)%></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% else %>
    <% @cocktails.each do |cocktail| %>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
        <div class="card"  style="background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.3), rgba(0,0,0,0.2)),
           url('<%= cl_image_path cocktail.photo %>');">

           <h2 class="card-description"><%= link_to cocktail.name, cocktail_path(cocktail)%></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

[This is my binding pry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkxej.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> @cocktail_search = @cocktails.where('cocktails.name LIKE ?', params[:query][:search])

If your table has column "**name**", then:

`@cocktail_search = @cocktails.where('name LIKE ?', params[:query][:search])`

should do the work.

When you're uncertain about what is wrong you can `rails console` and check things yourself, ex. `Coctail.where("name like ?", "Mojito")` and see if it returns expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use `LIKE` it seems like you want to find cocktails every if the search term matches only parts of the name. This can be archived by using `%` (see: [Safe ActiveRecord like query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26094593/2483313)).

Furthermore you might want to use a case-insensitive `ILIKE` instead of `LIKE`:

```
@cocktails.where('name ILIKE ?', "%#{params[:query][:search]}%")
```

Without the `%` you query is basically the same as

```
@cocktails.where(name: params[:query][:search])
```

that only returns exact matches.

Comment: Super ! I was also trying this but forgot to use double quotes for the interpolation...  Thanks for this :)