# Rails 5 best controller action to write a like query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I want to make an ajax search query by a client's name, so I'm using a like clause ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26094430/safe-activerecord-like-query)). I was thinking of using the index action to respond to json format from clients_controller but I'm already using it to repond to html format and at the same time paginates my listed rows with **will_paginate** and **will_paginate-bootstrap**.

What is the best way? making a new method to respond to json format or should I use the index one with format? and How to do that?

I'm new with ruby on rails

**clients_controller.rb**

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    {
       #something like this I know that I would return me a syntax error
       @client = Client.paginate(:page => params[:page])
    }
    format.json
    {
       #something like this I know that I would return me a syntax error
       @client = Client.where("client_name LIKE ? ", "%#{params[:client_name]}%"  )
    }
  end
end

def other_method
  @client = Client.where("client_name LIKE ? ", "%#{params[:client_name]}%"  )
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json {...}
  end
end
```

Comment: I think both ways are fine but if it were me, I would create a `search` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, you should keep only your `index` action and just accumulate the scopes on your `@client` variable.

Remember that your SQL query is only sent to the database when performing an Array method like `each` on your variable, not before.
So you can write something like:

```
def index
  @client = Client.all
  if params[:client_name].present?
    @client = @client.where("client_name LIKE ? ", "%#{params[:client_name]}%")
  else
    @client = @client.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new action with some fruitful name like `search` or `search_by_client_name` . It will solve your issue also and you will stick with rails restful routing.

If you want index action to serve both request then you can do something like this:

```
def index
  @client = Client.paginate(:page => params[:page])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json do
      client = Client.where("client_name LIKE ? ", "%#{params[:client_name]}%"
      render json: { client: client }
    end
  end
end
```