# rails formatting a json.jbuilder for jquery-ui autocomplete widget

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, jquery-ui

I'm using [autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp) widget of jquery-ui. I found that it sends its parameters as term and it needs a json like this

`[{"label": "Client1"},{"label": "Client2"} ]`

Instead I am getting

```
[{"client":{"label":"Cliente"}}]
```

**clients_controller.rb**

```
def index
  @client = Client.all
  @client = Client.paginate(:page => params[:page])
  if params[:term].present?
    @client = @client.where("client_name LIKE ? ", "%#{params[:term]}%")
  else
    @client = @client.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json
  end
end
```

**_client.json.jbuilder**

```
json.client do
  json.label client.client_name
end
```

How can I format a json as I needing it?

Answer (score 0):

use `json.(@client, :client_name)` instead of looping.

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error. I also tried `json.label(@clients, :client_name)` but it doesn't work either. Could you give me any other suggestions please? =)

Comment: I'm trying to render a json from a like query like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040615/rails-5-best-controller-action-to-write-a-like-query) one. But I also want to give client_name an label allias to return a json like this.

`[{"label": "Client1"},{"label": "Client2"} ]`

in wich label is actually **client_name** column.

Sorry if I'm not making myself clear. Feel free to ask any questions :)